# Check if VHD is x86 or not

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, vhd

Is there are a way to get if the OS is x86 or not ?
I tried get-VHD command and it doesn't seem to show me this information. is it even possible to get this information without hydrating a VM out of it?

Comment: Mount the VHD and check for the presence of a 'Program Files (x86)` folder in the root of the drive?

Comment: It exists even for 64 bit OS

Comment: Right, it shouldn't exist for 32 bit OS though.